# What is the possible reason for an EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION crash?

Tags: java, crash

I get this crash report when I run java bean of my project using eclipse. I have totally no idea what it is and how to debug. Can anyone tell me the possible way to debug this?

```
#
# An unexpected error has been detected by Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d801117, pid=2544, tid=2188
#
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105 mixed mode)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [jvm.dll+0x1117]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x03201400):  JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_native, id=2188]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x00000150

Registers:
EAX=0x00000000, EBX=0x032014e8, ECX=0x032013d0, EDX=0x00000004
ESP=0x0699e9cc, EBP=0x0699e9d0, ESI=0x00000000, EDI=0x00000000
EIP=0x6d801117, EFLAGS=0x00010246

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0699e9cc)
0x0699e9cc:   032014e8 0699e9ec 6d918c33 00000000
0x0699e9dc:   00000006 02db3be8 032014e8 00000000
0x0699e9ec:   0699ea08 78641463 032014e8 02db3be8
0x0699e9fc:   03201400 190342f8 190342f8 0699ea44
0x0699ea0c:   069aa460 032014e8 0699ea4c 0699ea54
0x0699ea1c:   00000007 78dda575 0699ea24 190342f8
0x0699ea2c:   0699ea54 190a0630 00000000 190342f8
0x0699ea3c:   00000000 0699ea54 0699ea78 069a2dd7 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d801117)
0x6d801107:   01 00 00 5e 5d c3 cc cc cc 55 8b ec 56 8b 75 08
0x6d801117:   c7 86 50 01 00 00 05 00 00 00 83 3d bc fa a6 6d 


Stack: [0x061a0000,0x069a0000),  sp=0x0699e9cc,  free space=8186k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [jvm.dll+0x1117]
C  [jvm.dll+0x118c33]
C  0x78641463
j  java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Float.<clinit>()V+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Class;+0
j  java.lang.Float.<clinit>()V+2
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  java.util.HashMap.<init>(IF)V+56
j  java.util.HashMap.<init>(I)V+4
j  sun.misc.SoftCache.<init>(I)V+26
j  java.lang.Thread.<clinit>()V+28
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
=>0x03201400 JavaThread "Unknown thread" [_thread_in_native, id=2188]

Other Threads:
  0x02e2b400 VMThread [id=1184]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 14784K, used 263K [0x11020000, 0x12020000, 0x13020000)
  eden space 13184K,   2% used [0x11020000, 0x11061ec8, 0x11d00000)
  from space 1600K,   0% used [0x11d00000, 0x11d00000, 0x11e90000)
  to   space 1600K,   0% used [0x11e90000, 0x11e90000, 0x12020000)
 tenured generation   total 49152K, used 0K [0x13020000, 0x16020000, 0x19020000)
   the space 49152K,   0% used [0x13020000, 0x13020000, 0x13020200, 0x16020000)
 compacting perm gen  total 32768K, used 518K [0x19020000, 0x1b020000, 0x1d020000)
   the space 32768K,   1% used [0x19020000, 0x190a1a00, 0x190a1a00, 0x1b020000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe
0x7c900000 - 0x7c9b2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ntdll.dll
0x7c800000 - 0x7c8f6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\kernel32.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10063000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\SYSFER.DLL
0x77dd0000 - 0x77e6b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77e70000 - 0x77f02000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x77fe0000 - 0x77ff1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\Secur32.dll
0x7e410000 - 0x7e4a1000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USER32.dll
0x77f10000 - 0x77f59000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\GDI32.dll
0x76390000 - 0x763ad000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x629c0000 - 0x629c9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\LPK.DLL
0x74d90000 - 0x74dfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USP10.dll
0x00b50000 - 0x00b67000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Logitech\LVMVFM\LVPrcInj.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d800000 - 0x6daa7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x76b40000 - 0x76b6d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x6d7b0000 - 0x6d7bc000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d330000 - 0x6d34f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d290000 - 0x6d298000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\hpi.dll
0x76bf0000 - 0x76bfb000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6d7ff000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x6d000000 - 0x6d14a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\awt.dll
0x73000000 - 0x73026000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x77c10000 - 0x77c68000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x774e0000 - 0x7761d000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\ole32.dll
0x773d0000 - 0x774d3000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.2600.5512_x-ww_35d4ce83\COMCTL32.dll
0x77f60000 - 0x77fd6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x5ad70000 - 0x5ada8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\uxtheme.dll
0x74720000 - 0x7476c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x755c0000 - 0x755ee000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msctfime.ime
0x68000000 - 0x68036000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x769c0000 - 0x76a74000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\USERENV.dll
0x5b860000 - 0x5b8b5000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\netapi32.dll
0x6d610000 - 0x6d623000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\net.dll
0x71ab0000 - 0x71ac7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x71aa0000 - 0x71aa8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WS2HELP.dll
0x71a50000 - 0x71a8f000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\mswsock.dll
0x76f20000 - 0x76f47000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fb8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\winrnr.dll
0x76f60000 - 0x76f8c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WLDAP32.dll
0x76fc0000 - 0x76fc6000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x03590000 - 0x035c3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\idmmbc.dll
0x77120000 - 0x771ab000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x662b0000 - 0x66308000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\hnetcfg.dll
0x71a90000 - 0x71a98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x6d700000 - 0x6d706000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\rmi.dll
0x03880000 - 0x03899000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\jacob-1.14.3-x86.dll
0x78130000 - 0x781cb000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_x-ww_b80fa8ca\MSVCR80.dll
0x76fd0000 - 0x7704f000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\CLBCATQ.DLL
0x77050000 - 0x77115000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\COMRes.dll
0x77c00000 - 0x77c08000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\VERSION.dll
0x038d0000 - 0x03b95000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\xpsp2res.dll
0x11000000 - 0x11015000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MobitekSMSAPI5.dll
0x73420000 - 0x73573000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSVBVM60.DLL
0x7e720000 - 0x7e7d0000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\SXS.DLL
0x7d1e0000 - 0x7d49c000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\msi.dll
0x04110000 - 0x04122000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\rxtxSerial.dll
0x73d90000 - 0x73db7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\crtdll.dll
0x21c10000 - 0x21c2a000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\MSCOMM32.OCX
0x6d230000 - 0x6d284000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\fontmanager.dll
0x7c9c0000 - 0x7d1d7000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\shell32.dll
0x6d630000 - 0x6d639000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\nio.dll
0x048d0000 - 0x048d7000     C:\Program Files\WWW.HOSTJSC.NET\Internet Download Manager\idmmkb.dll
0x04ae0000 - 0x04ce2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\nativemcl77.dll
0x04d00000 - 0x04d6a000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mclmcrrt77.dll
0x7c420000 - 0x7c4a7000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.3053_x-ww_b80fa8ca\MSVCP80.dll
0x7ac50000 - 0x7ac9f000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmx.dll
0x7ab80000 - 0x7ac4e000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libut.dll
0x76c90000 - 0x76cb8000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\imagehlp.dll
0x789a0000 - 0x78b62000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\xerces-c_2_7.dll
0x7af20000 - 0x7aff7000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\icuuc36.dll
0x7a770000 - 0x7a774000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\icudt36.dll
0x7a9e0000 - 0x7aaa2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\icuin36.dll
0x7a780000 - 0x7a78c000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\icuio36.dll
0x78620000 - 0x78632000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\zlib1.dll
0x78540000 - 0x78560000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmat.dll
0x7aab0000 - 0x7ab78000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libhdf5.dll
0x05a60000 - 0x05b0d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mclmcr.dll
0x796e0000 - 0x79713000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mcr.dll
0x78500000 - 0x78518000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\bridge.dll
0x7a790000 - 0x7a79d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\iqm.dll
0x7aca0000 - 0x7aeba000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwservices.dll
0x7aec0000 - 0x7af1d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwmathutil.dll
0x79120000 - 0x79154000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mpath.dll
0x763b0000 - 0x763f9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\comdlg32.dll
0x7a7b0000 - 0x7a7be000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmex.dll
0x79550000 - 0x795a4000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\m_dispatcher.dll
0x78520000 - 0x7853c000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\datasvcs.dll
0x79c60000 - 0x7a0f2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\m_interpreter.dll
0x7a810000 - 0x7a819000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwmathrng.dll
0x790e0000 - 0x79111000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\m_ir.dll
0x79790000 - 0x79c58000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\m_parser.dll
0x7a7a0000 - 0x7a7ac000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\ir_xfmr.dll
0x782e0000 - 0x783df000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mcos.dll
0x7a840000 - 0x7a84a000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mtok.dll
0x78580000 - 0x78595000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\m_pcodegen.dll
0x785a0000 - 0x785b2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\m_pcodeio.dll
0x79460000 - 0x794a7000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\profiler.dll
0x7a760000 - 0x7a76d000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\boost_thread-vc80-mt-1_33_1.dll
0x7a640000 - 0x7a6c8000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\udd.dll
0x79410000 - 0x79458000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\comcli.dll
0x79020000 - 0x79055000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\jmi.dll
0x71ad0000 - 0x71ad9000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x7a6d0000 - 0x7a75b000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\uiw.dll
0x7b000000 - 0x7b0d6000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwgui.dll
0x78d40000 - 0x78d6a000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwhardcopy.dll
0x790a0000 - 0x790d2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libuij.dll
0x7a880000 - 0x7a889000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\uinone.dll
0x781d0000 - 0x782df000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.MFC_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_x-ww_3bf8fa05\MFC80.DLL
0x7c630000 - 0x7c64b000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_Microsoft.VC80.ATL_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_8.0.50727.762_x-ww_cbb27474\ATL80.DLL
0x78680000 - 0x787e8000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\hg.dll
0x787f0000 - 0x7899e000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\numerics.dll
0x7a7c0000 - 0x7a7c7000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwamd.dll
0x794b0000 - 0x79508000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwcholmod.dll
0x7a7f0000 - 0x7a7f7000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwcolamd.dll
0x78560000 - 0x7857a000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwlapack.dll
0x7a7d0000 - 0x7a7dc000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwbinder.dll
0x7a7e0000 - 0x7a7e9000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwblas.dll
0x7a800000 - 0x7a807000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwcsparse.dll
0x78d70000 - 0x78d96000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwma57.dll
0x7a930000 - 0x7a9d9000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libifcoremd.dll
0x79160000 - 0x7940c000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmmd.dll
0x79670000 - 0x796dc000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libmwumfpack.dll
0x7a5b0000 - 0x7a638000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libfftw3.dll
0x7a890000 - 0x7a92c000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\libfftw3f.dll
0x7a830000 - 0x7a83b000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mlautoregister.dll
0x785c0000 - 0x785d2000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\mwoles05.DLL
0x79720000 - 0x79785000     C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\udd_mi.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xss512k -XX:PermSize=32M -Xms64m -XX:NewRatio=3 -XX:MaxPermSize=64M -Xmx128m -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1200000000 -Dsun.java2d.noddraw=true -Dsun.awt.nopixfmt=true -Xshare:off -Djava.library.path=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32 vfprintf abort
java_command: <unknown>
Launcher Type: generic

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
PATH=C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32\;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/lib/i386;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\binn\;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2007b\bin\win32;C:\Python26;C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\django\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\X10\Common;C:\Python26\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Thunder Network\KanKan\Codecs;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21\bin;C:\wizz\InstantRails20\ruby\bin;C:\wizz\arduino-0021;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Component Runtime\v77\runtime\win32;C:\grails\bin;C:\Program Files\WinAnt\bin
USERNAME=Administrator
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 15 Stepping 13, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows XP Build 2600 Service Pack 3

CPU:total 2 family 6, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2

Memory: 4k page, physical 1038572k(39276k free), swap 2500092k(1143492k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (1.6.0-b105) for windows-x86, built on Nov 29 2006 00:48:48 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1310
```

Comment: "Access violation" means memory corruption (a.k.a. a bug), though I have no idea what could be causing it.

Comment: As already suggested, try the latest jre, currently 1.6.0_23, and see if that fixes the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the JVM is crashing. Not much you can do to debug this, really, short of looking for a patch for the problem.

I'm pretty sure that version "1.6.0-b105" denotes the very first release (or one of the very first) of Java6, though. That's pretty old already.

I *strongly* suggest you upgrade to the current version (1.6.0_23, at time of writing this). This will very likely resolve your problem.

Comment: I try update jre and untill now it haven't crash yet! Thanks!